# Calling class properties from within protocol extension

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

In using protocol extension for default implementation I encounter a problem. I define a protocol with different optional properties and functions to use. In the extension I implement a default function and nil properties. In the implementation I use properties and functions from within the protocol.

On the device it works how I expect. Also on the debugger it gave me the property from the class when I run into breakpoint within the extension implementation.

Can someone help me out why I didn't get the property in the example from the class but the nil property from extension.

Example from playground

```
import UIKit

protocol Collectable {

    var item: String?  { get }
    func collect()
}

extension Collectable {
    var item: String?  { return nil }
    func collect() {
        if let some = item {
            print("collect \(some)")
        } else {
            print("nothing")
        }
    }
}

class Car: Collectable {
    var item = "letter"
}

let car = Car()
car.collect()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the protocol your item is optional string, while in your class you declared another variable named also item. Your collect function is looking for the optional item, and in the extension you specified that it should return nil.

Comment: Could argue this is a bug. The compiler should perhaps complain "hey, you're trying to inject `item` into Car when it's already got an `item` of a different type."

Comment: Agreed; it shouldn't be legal to have conflicting types for `item` via an extension. I'd submit this to bugs.swift.org.

Answer (score 1):

As @SavcaMarin stated in their answer, you have a type conflict between the `item` property declared in your extension (`String?`) and the one in your `Car` (`String`).

You can see this if you comment the extension.  The compiler will tell you that `Car` does not conform to `Collectable`.  If you ask it to create the required stubs it will create `func collect` and `var item: String?`.  It then gives an error that `item` is re-defined.

As Rob and Matt pointed out in comments on the other answer, this seems to be a bug in the Swift compiler. It doesn't indicate the re-definition of `item` or the non-conformance of your `item` to the protocol if there is a default implementation that satisfies the protocol conformance (your extension).

The simple fix is to tell Swift that the `item` in `Car` is the same as item in `Collectable` by declaring the type explicitly (`String?`) rather than relying on type inference (Which gives `String`):

```
class Car: Collectable {    
    var item:String? = "letter"
}
```